# Is the CMV promoter active in yeast?

Tags: yeast

I wish to transfect yeast and want to control my efficiency. So I thought to use pEGFP-N1 as control. The EGFP is driven by a CMV promoter. Can yeast read CMV promoters.
Thanks
Hermann

Answer (score 3):

Yes ([reference](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC125456/))

While I found your question interesting this was pretty much the first hit when I typed "CMV yeast" in google scholar. You should really look there first before you ask!